# How to Insert the primary key in the database by the user

Tags: php, cakephp, primary-key

I'm working cakephp3. after bakery,for example users table, add action, in my project, id (primarykey) should be filled by the user that cake does'nt show id (primarykey) to the user. I used `echo $this->Form->input('id',['type' => 'number']);`  but id does'nt insert to database. 
How to add primarykey by user?

**add.ctp**

```
 <?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
<fieldset>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id',['type' => 'number']);
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

**function add()**

```
public function add() {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $roles = $this->Users->Roles->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $dormitories = $this->Users->Dormitories->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('user', 'roles', 'dormitories'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

Comment: Set id as autoincrement value in your database.

Comment: id must be filled by the user so it should not be autoincrement.

Comment: As you wish. But it's sounds like a bad idea... Maybe look at your Entity if there is not id => false in $_accessible variable?

Comment: And maybe, try to set it like this?: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment